# which microsoft server version to choose

Tags: windows

Our company needs a windows server. however, when i look at list of different versions, i get confused. For example, there are so many OEM versions, updates and versions specific to vendor like DELL or HP. Which one do i choose and which is the best place to buy it?
...
so needs are very basic. Basic environment and active directory (also in basic level). By basic environment i mean stable OS, that can support regular server software like webserver, exchange server, database server. 
...
Bugdet is up to 500$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question might be more suitable for [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com). However, if you don't have too many users and this will be the only server there, it sounds like Small Business Server is what you need.

Comment: In future i will ask questions like this in other places. But thank you for reply.